# Why hasn't SVXY recouped more of its lost value as vol has crashed in the past 2 weeks?

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, etf, vix

SVXY fell from around \$140 to \$9. It has since bounced back 25% to around \$12.

Vix futures went from the 11-14 range to 35 and now back to 17-18.

SVXY holds a short position in Vix futures with an average weighted maturity of 1 month. Why didn't SVXY recoup much more of its lost value when vol dropped sharply after the "volpocalypse"?

I get that the curve was (and is) in backwardation and so SVXY loses some money from that daily (but that should be a tiny amount).

Comment: SVXY now uses reduced leverage to avoid the fate of its cousin https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2018-02-27/proshares-slashes-leverage-on-surviving-volatility-products

Comment: That's only as of today.

Comment: Have a read through the prospectus.  Hint: SVXY's only purpose is to give daily exposure.

Comment: Are you trying to hint that it only tracks performance during market hours and that the majority of the fall in vix futures happened after-hours every day?